# How do I use an or in a tcl switch statement?

Tags: tcl

I want to have a large list of options in my script. The user is going to give input that will only match one of those options. I want to be able to have multiple different options run the same commands but I cannot seem to get ORs working. Below is what I thought it should look like, any ideas on how to make the a or b line work?

```
switch -glob -- $opt {
   "a" || "b" {
      puts "you selected a or b, probably not both"
   }
   default {
      puts "Your choice did not match anything"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `-` as the body for a case, to fall-through to the next body, as explained in the [Tcl Manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/switch.htm):

> If a body is specified as “-” it means that the body for the next
>   pattern should also be used as the body for this pattern (if the next
>   pattern also has a body of “-” then the body after that is used, and
>   so on). This feature makes it possible to share a single body among
>   several patterns.

Also, if your options are a big string of concatentated characters, you are going to have to bookend your option patterns with wildcards, or your cases will only match when `opt` only contains a single option:

```
switch -glob -- $opt {
   "*a*" -
   "*b*" {
      puts "you selected a or b, probably not both"
   }
   default {
      puts "Your choice did not match anything"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also working this:

```
switch -regexp -- $opt {
   a|b {
      puts "you selected a or b, probably not both"
   }
   default {
      puts "Your choice did not match anything"
   }
}
```

Attention: no spaces between "a|b"

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways. From [the switch documentation examples](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/switch.htm#M12): "Using glob matching and the fall-through body is an alternative to writing regular expressions with alternations..."